# CMD Redirection not Working — .exe Opens New Window

Tags: cmd, window, pipe, output

Windows 7.

I may (or may not) have done something to the Firmware in my video card.  I am trying to run nvflash, to investigate and fix the problem.

The whole scenario has been plagued by numerous appalling inadequacies, including the fact that the @BIOS installer does not tell you the name nor location of the program being installed.  For all I know, nvflash is the wrong program.

I am trying (at this stage) to run "nvflash /a", to get a list of applicable (and seen) video cards.

Each time I execute the command in the CMD window, it opens a new window, displays the output there and then immediately closes the window.

I have tried using  |  >  and  >>  and (after teething problems with these) I am getting no error messages, but not output in the text file.

The command I am using is as follows.

```
nvflash /a >> "c:\users\adminaccount\my documents\out001.txt"
```

I have also tried adding   2>&1   .

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

p.s.  As usual, I note that I resent my [spaces added for readability] being deleted.  If the commands are obscure... don't blame me.

p.p.s.  I don't understand why it is not originally designed to display useable output.

Answer (score 0):

(Disclaimer: I don't know anything about the internals of nvflash)

I would suspect that `>>` (append to file) expects a file to exist on which further lines can be appended. Use `>` instead to always create and overwrite the file.

Also... does nvflash open up a `window`(=GUI Window) or a `command window` (=console window like the one from cmd.exe). If it is the latter one, then nvflash internally does not write to standard out (that is, the already existing cmd window) but creates a new cmd.exe process to write to... in both cases the redirect with `>` or `>>` won't work :(